# How to calculate euclidean distance between pair of rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have a `numpy` array like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,0,1,0],
             [1,1,0,0],
             [1,0,1,0],
             [0,0,1,1]])
```

I would like to calculate `euclidian distance` between each pair of rows.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    d = [np.sqrt(np.sum((a[i]-a[j])**2)) for j in range(i+1,a.shape[0])]
    print(d)
```

> [1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951]
>
> [1.4142135623730951, 2.0]
>
> [1.4142135623730951]
>
> []

Is there any better pythonic way to do this since i have to run this code on a huge `numpy` array?

Comment: Do the points have arbitrary dimensions, or is it always 4d?

Comment: Did you look at : `distance.pdist`? That should solve it with : `distance.pdist(a)`. What's should be the final output like?

Comment: @Divakar among euclidean distance between all pair of row vectors I want the k farthest vectors.

Comment: @divakar Sir, that worked

Comment: Also, have a look at at KDTree - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And for completeness, einsum is often referenced for distance calculations.

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1,0],
         [1,1,0,0],
         [1,0,1,0],
         [0,0,1,1]])

b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], 1, a.shape[1])

np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk, ijk->ij', a-b, a-b))

array([[ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.41421356,  2.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 15):

In terms of something more "elegant" you could always use scikitlearn pairwise euclidean distance:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
euclidean_distances(a,a)
```

having the same output as a single array.

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 1.41421356,  2.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: I think it is giving me the euclidean distance between each pair of points but I want it between each pair of rows. Consider one row represents one 1d vector.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention it in my question that one row is one 1d vector.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I got it wrong. Each entry is the distance between ith and jth row of an mXn array where i< j<m.

Answer (score 0):

I used `itertools.combinations` together with `np.linalg.norm` of the difference vector (this is the euclidean distance):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
a = np.array([[1,0,1,0],
              [1,1,0,0],
              [1,0,1,0],
              [0,0,1,1]])

print([np.linalg.norm(x[0]-x[1]) for x in itertools.combinations(a, 2)])
```

For understanding have a look at this example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html):
`combinations('ABCD', 2)` gives `AB AC AD BC BD CD`. In your case, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are the rows of your matrix `a`, so the term `x[0]-x[1]` appearing in the above code is the difference vector of the vectors in the rows of `a`.