# How to check overlap between to particle in Molecular Dynamics

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo

Suppose I have 10 particles and each particle have three co-ordinates. I want to place them randomly such that distance between two particle will be always greater than some value(say 1). 
Any idea how to do that.

Comment: A simple suggestion is to: (i) randomise 3 values (x, y, z), (ii) compare the new coordinate with all old coordinates, (iii) if the distance > _some value_, place it, otherwise, go to _i_. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried but that is not able to remove the overlap completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't mention that the particles are restricted to be in some volume, i.e. they can be anywhere in R^3, you could just introduce random numbers with

```
n = 10
pos = np.random.random(3*n).reshape(n,3)
```

then calculate all the pairwise distances, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367001/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-pair-of-rows-of-a-numpy-array/43367461#43367461) on how to efficiently do that, and then divide the whole array `pos` with the minimum distance (in case you use the value `1` to be the distance that no two particles should ever have less than).