# Efficient distance for clustering computation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to compute the distance from a set of N 3D-points to a set of M 3D-centers and store the results in a NxM matrix (where column i is the distance from all points to center i)

Example:

```
data  = np.random.rand(100,3)   # 100 toy 3D points
centers = np.random.rand(20,3)  # 20 toy 3D points
```

For computing the distance between all points and a single center we can use "broadcasting" so we avoid looping though all points:

```
i = 0     # first center
np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(data - centers[i,:], 2),1))  # Euclidean distance
```

Now we can put this code in a loop that iterates over all centers:

```
distances = np.zeros(data.shape[0], centers.shape[0])
for i in range(centers.shape[0]):
    distances[:,i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(data - centers[i,:], 2),1))
```

However this is clearly an operation that could be parallelized and improved.

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this (maybe some multi-dimensional broadcasting or some library).

This is a very common problem for clustering and classification, where you want to get distances from your data to a set of classes, so I think it should be some efficient implementation to to this.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: options on this topic are numerous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367001/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-pair-of-rows-of-a-numpy-array/43368088#43368088

Comment: do you know scikit-learn : http://scikit-learn.org/ ? you will find lot of method for classification

Comment: to be more specific, you probably want to use the paiwise distance function (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43367358/5786475) or instanciate a k-means method (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) with your centers and request the distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast all the way:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(100,3)
centers = np.random.rand(20,3)
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(data[:,None,:] - centers[None,:,:], 2), axis=-1))
print distances.shape
# 100, 20
```

If you just want the nearest center, and you have a lot of data points (a lot being more than a several 100 000 samples), you probably should store your data in a KD tree and query that with the centers (`scipy.spatial.KDTree`).