# Efficient way to compute element wise euclidiant distance between Two 3D matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

l have two 3D matrices. `matrix1=dim(15,3)` and `matrix2=dim(23,3)`.

for instance :

```
matrix1=[[5,7,8],
[10,6,8],
...
...
...,
[11,14,78]]
```

and

```
matrix2=[[3,7,9],
[12,11,18],
...,
...,
[78,99,10]]
```

**What would be the output ?**

`matrix_distance=dim(15,23)`
for the sake of illustration lets consider only the first channel and the first row :

```
matrix_distance[:,:,0]=[(5-3)^2, (5-12)^2, ..., (5-78)^2]
```

What is the efficient and vectorized way to compute it ?

**EDIT1:**

Non vectorized solution

```
for i in np.arange(len(matrix1)):
    for j in np.arange(len(matrix2)):
        for channel in np.arange(matrix1[0,0,:]):
            matrix_distance[i,:,p]=(matrix1[i,:,p]-matrix2[j,:,p])^2
```

a=[[5,7,8]]

b=[[3,7,9],[3,7,9],[78,99,10]]

then

```
c=[[(5-3)^2,(7-7)^2,(8-9)^2],[(5-3)^2,(7-7)^2,(8-9)^2],[(5-78)^2,(7-99)^2,(8-10)^2]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate euclidean distance between pair of rows of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367001/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-pair-of-rows-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: The expected output does not make sense (three indices into a 2D array; Do you want distances between all pairs of 3-element vectors?) How would you simply and inefficiently compute the distances? Try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kazemakase, yes l would like to compute distances between all pairs of 3-elements. let's say matrix1[0]=[5,7,8]  l would like to compute distance with all vectors of matrix2=[[3,7,9],
[12,11,18],
...,
...,
[78,99,10]] . Hope it's clear. For my output,  l mentionned atrix_distance[:,:,0] for the first value of vector and atrix_distance[:,:,1] for the second value of a vector and atrix_distance[:,:,2] for the third value of a vector

Comment: Not entirely clear yet. In the end you want a total number 15*23*3 distances, and each distance is the squared difference of two scalar values? It's often easier to describe the problem in code than in words. Please just show us non-vectorized code that yields exactly the solution you want. Then it's hopefully easy for people to show you how to vectorize it.

Comment: Thanks. Your code still seems a bit confused regarding dimensions, but I think you will want `matrix_distance = (matrix1[:, None, :] - matrix2[None, :, :])**2`  (Note that in Python the power operator is `**` not `^` as in Matlab.)

Comment: @kazemakase, please see my update. l try to make it more clear hopefully. Imagine you have two RGB images. Each image have i rows and j column and 3 channels image1=[i,j,:]  image2=[i,j,:] and you want to compute euclidian distance between the two images

Comment: What is p in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scipy's [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

```
In [8]: cdist(matrix1,matrix2).shape
Out[8]: (15, 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to scipy's cdist you can also use Numba, which provides better performance. Also think of using only 32bit floats for calculation if that satisfies your precision requirements.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

#Maybe calculation with 32bit floats is sufficient?
#creating random 32bit floats
vec_1=np.array(np.random.rand(10000,3),dtype=np.float32)
vec_2=np.array(np.random.rand(20000,3),dtype=np.float32)


@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_distance(vec_1,vec_2):
    assert vec_1.shape[1]==3 #Enable SIMD-Vectorization (adding some performance)
    assert vec_2.shape[1]==3 #Enable SIMD-Vectorization (adding some performance)

    res=np.empty((vec_1.shape[0],vec_2.shape[0]),dtype=vec_1.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(vec_1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(vec_2.shape[0]):
            res[i,j]=np.sqrt((vec_1[i,0]-vec_2[j,0])**2+(vec_1[i,1]-vec_2[j,1])**2+(vec_1[i,2]-vec_2[j,2])**2)

    return res

t1=time.time()
res=calc_distance(vec_1,vec_2)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
A=cdist(vec_1,vec_2) #cdist approach
print(time.time()-t1)
```

This gives on a quadcore i7-4.Gen 0.25s (Numba), 1.3s cdist. Calculation with 64-bit-precision gives 0.44s (Numba).