# memory efficient euclidean distance measurement

Tags: python, scipy

I have 40,000 points and I need to find out the euclidean distance between each of the pairs. After going through the net, I found that the efficient way of calculating euclidean distance between pairs of points is by using scipy.spatial distance.cdist. But, since the no. of points is 40,000, the distance matirx will take around 12 GB of memory.

Is there a way of reducing the memory required to store the distance matrix without compromising the speed of calculating the same? Can the data type be change to float 32 instead of float 64 in the calculation of the distance matrix?

Comment: Use lazy evaluation?

Comment: Split your points into n subarrays, then perform your calculation n^2 times? Similar to lazy evaluation, but you just use the tools you mentioned.

Comment: I suspect that behind the scenes, `cdist` uses float64 (C doubles) everywhere, so that may not matter much. But that's easy to find out with a smaller array, using both input data types, and comparing the memory usage.

Comment: Yes you can use float32. A little modification to this code should do what you wan't and is also faster than cdist. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490630/4045774

Comment: @Evert: cdist uses float 64. When using large points, it then becomes a memory intensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cdist like approach**

The output datatype is the same as given as input.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_distance(vec_1,vec_2):
    res=np.empty((vec_1.shape[0],vec_2.shape[0]),dtype=vec_1.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(vec_1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(vec_2.shape[0]):
            res[i,j]=np.sqrt((vec_1[i,0]-vec_2[j,0])**2+(vec_1[i,1]-vec_2[j,1])**2+(vec_1[i,2]-vec_2[j,2])**2)

    return res
```

**Aproach without repetitions**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def calc_distance_pairs(vec):
  res=np.empty(((vec.shape[0]**2)//2-vec.shape[0]//2),dtype=vec.dtype)

  ii=0
  for i in range(vec.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i+1,vec.shape[0]):
      res[ii]=np.sqrt((vec[i,0]-vec[j,0])**2+(vec[i,1]-vec[j,1])**2+(vec[i,2]-vec[j,2])**2)
      ii+=1

  return res
```

This cuts the amount of memory to less than 1/4 of the scipy cdist approach.

**Timings**

```
calc_distance: ~2s
calc_distance_pairs: ~3s
cdist: ~11s
```

Comment: Thank you very much